# Multiple Ractive components

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

At the moment it is not possible to use more then one component in a template. For example:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <LeftColumn>
  <RightColumn>
  <p>text here</p>
</div>
```

Ractive displays only the first one. The situation is the same if I want to use same component tag twice. It's even more strange when I have only one component but place something after the tag (the `<p>text here</p>` above). It is not displayed too.
Here is a JSBin showing the problem http://jsbin.com/maxen/3/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either add closing `</widget>` tag or use self-closing syntax - `<widget />`. [Demo here](http://jsbin.com/putopuhiqanu/1/edit).